# Raspberry Pi thinks button is constantly being pressed

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I am using buttons to turn an LED on and off using a raspberry pi. The two buttons have been working fine, but for some reason, in a particular function, one seems to think that it is constantly being pressed. This is not the case in other functions, and the code for the other button appears to be identical so I'm struggling to identify the problem.

```
while True: 
    if GPIO.input(4) == 0:
        time.sleep(0.4)
        (continues with program)
    elif GPIO.input(24) == 0:  
        time.sleep(0.4)
        (continues with program)
```

The first one works fine, however with the second, whether it is set to '0' or '1', it thinks that it is constantly being pressed. If anyone could offer any suggestions, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Can you show us enough code to reproduce the problem? Show us where how you're initializing the GPIO lines, code that works correctly, and code that doesn't work.

Comment: It won't let me post all of the code in a comment, so I've posted it in another question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raspberry Pi seems to think button is constantly being pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59697769/raspberry-pi-seems-to-think-button-is-constantly-being-pressed)

Comment: Did you setup the pullup resistor? http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#set_pull_up_down