# Raspberry Pi seems to think button is constantly being pressed

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I am using buttons to turn an LED on and off using a raspberry pi. The two buttons have been working fine, but for some reason, in a particular function, one seems to think that it is constantly being pressed. This is not the case in other functions, and the code for the other button appears to be identical so I'm struggling to identify the problem. The PIR sensor also works fine.

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
PIR_PIN = 7
GPIO.setup(PIR_PIN, GPIO.IN)
btn_pin = 4#first button
led_pin = 12#LED
btn_pin2 = 24#second button
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(btn_pin, GPIO.IN)#first button
GPIO.setup(led_pin, GPIO.OUT)#LED
GPIO.setup(btn_pin2, GPIO.IN)#second button
GPIO.output(12, GPIO.LOW)#turn LED off
light = 0
count = 0
account = 0

while True:
    if GPIO.input(4) == 0:
        time.sleep(0.4)
        if light == 0:
            GPIO.output(12, GPIO.HIGH)
            print('On')
            light = 1
        else:
            GPIO.output(12, GPIO.LOW)#Turn light off
            print('Off')
            light = 0
            w = open('Database3.txt', 'r')
            for line in w:
                account = line
            w.close()
            g = open('Database2.txt', 'r')
            temp = open('temp_file', 'w')
            for line in g:
                CurrentLine = line.split(',')
                if CurrentLine[0] == account:
                    current = CurrentLine[5]#retrieves current energy stats
                    print(current)#Check for correct value
                    current_value = float(current)#Declares a float
                    current_value = current_value + count#Adds on current use
                    print(current_value)
                    current = str(current_value)#Declares a string
                    CurrentLine[5] = (current)#Updates value
                OutputLine = ','.join(CurrentLine)
                temp.write(OutputLine)#Writes data to temporary file
            g.close()#Closes file
            temp.close()#Closes file
            os.remove('Database2.txt')#Removes original file
            os.rename('temp_file', 'Database2.txt')#Renames current file
            count = 0

    if GPIO.input(24) == 0:
        time.sleep(2)#Allows for daily average to be calculated
        GPIO.output(12, GPIO.LOW)#Turns light off
        #print('Off')
        w = open('Database3.txt', 'r')
        for line in w:
            account = line
        w.close()
        light = 0
        print('New day')
        temp = open('temp_file', 'w')
        h = open('Database2.txt', 'r')
        print(account)
        for line in h:
            CurrentLine = line.split(',')
            if CurrentLine[0] == account:
                    days = CurrentLine[4]#retrieves current energy stats
                    #print(days)#Check for correct value
                    num_days = float(days)#Declares an integer

                    total = CurrentLine[6]#retrieves current energy stats
                    #print(total)#Check for correct value
                    total_num = float(total)#Declares an float

                    today = CurrentLine[5]
                    today_float = float(today)

                    total_num = total_num + today_float
                    print('total energy: ',total_num,)

                    DailyAverage = total_num/num_days
                    DailyAverageStr = str(DailyAverage)
                    num_days = num_days + 1#Adds an extra day

                    total = str(total_num)#Declares a string
                    days = str(num_days)
                    print('num days: ',num_days,)

                    CurrentLine[4] = days
                    CurrentLine[6] = (total)#Updates value
                    CurrentLine[5] = '0'#Resets the energy use for 'today'
                    CurrentLine[7] = DailyAverageStr
            OutputLine = ','.join(CurrentLine) 
            temp.write(OutputLine)#Writes data to temporary file
        h.close()#Closes file
        temp.close()#Closes file
        os.remove('Database2.txt')#Removes original file
        os.rename('temp_file', 'Database2.txt')#Renames current file

    if GPIO.input(PIR_PIN):
        if light == 1:
            print('Motion Detected')
            print('Turn the lights off!')
            count = count + 1
            time.sleep(1)
```

The first one works fine, however with the second, whether it is set to '0' or '1', it thinks that it is constantly being pressed. If anyone could offer any suggestions, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure built-in PULL-UP resistor

```py
GPIO.setup(btn_pin2, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
```

**Explanation:**

When you connect RPI's pin to any digital circuit (like PIR sensor) with digital output there is a guarantee that there will be some stable voltage on RPI pin , i.e. either logical "0" or "1".

Button on the other hand does not provides any reference voltage (when depressed) because it has only 2 "pins" without power and without any electronics in it.

Typically buttons are used in combination with

- either pull-up resistor with button shorting to ground (to provide "1" signal in "unpressed state")
- or pull-down resistor and button shorting power line when pressed (to provide "0" signal when button is depressed)

BCM SoC contains built-in resistors which can be used to setup input signal in case pin dangles in the air (i.e. when used with button without extra resistor).

`setup` method has third parameter which sets up pull-up/pull-down resistors.

> setup(channel(s), direction, pull_up_down=PUD_OFF, initial=None)

By default PUD(pull-up-down) mode is initialized with PUD_OFF value which is good when you connect RPI device to digital output of external digital circuit.

But you need to explicitly specify PUD mode when you use dangling pin for input purpose.

PS: [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/76667/debouncing-buttons-with-rpi-gpio-too-many-events-detected) can be of interest for you.